# Nexus 3 - upload 3rdParty artifact with curl.exe

Tags: curl, nexus, sonatype, artifact

Is it possible to upload `3rdParty artifacts` to Nexus 3 repository with curl.exe?

I have tried the following command to upload an artifact to a `maven2` repository:

```
curl -v -F r=MyRepository -F hasPom=false -F e=rar -F g=com.test -F a=project -F v=1.0 -F p=rar -F file="C:\TEMP\My3rdPartyFile.rar" -u USER:PASSWORD http://<SERVERNAME>:8081/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content
```

I have used -v parameter of curl.exe but no console output occured. The artifact is not in the repository and no error occured.

Is this the correct repository type?

Answer (score 1):

This API is not available in Nexus 3.  See https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-11894

Answer (score 0):

For a file upload this one should be either of the following (remember the `\\` while using back slash) with `@` character. Otherwise it will not upload the content of the file.

```
-F "file=@C:\\TEMP\\My3rdPartyFile.rar"

-F "file=@C:/TEMP/My3rdPartyFile.rar"
```

Another thing, is it always -F for other parameters (i.e.e `-F v=1.0`). Shouldn't it be `-d` instead of `-F` for the others (not sure though).

Comment: Unfortunately still not working :( I used -F "file=@C:\\TEMP\\My3rdPartyFile.rar". Also, I tried with -d for each other parameter. I got still no console-output from curl.exe.

Comment: Can you please try with adding `-v` with your curl and update the question with debug output? It will help others (who are better than me) to understand the problem and help you.

Comment: hi @Daniel its not only the `-v`, it's the output you have after adding -v in console. -v actually prints all the debug output that curl is doing. It helps to trace the error or other issues that is not good.

Comment: Please see above! no console output occured